# How to replace all the Char or string of an array to "X" by the user input?

Tags: java, arrays, replace

```
package machineproblem;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] classes ={{"A","B","C"},{"D","E","F"}};

        String userclass, userletter = null;

        do {



            System.out.println("/-----------------------------/");
            System.out.print("First Class: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++) 
        {

            System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [0][i] + " " + "]");

        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Economy Class: ");

        for (int x = 0; x <= classes.length; x++) 
        {
            System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [1][x] + " " + "]"); 
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("/-----------------------------/");

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("What class would you like? F/E: ");
        userclass = input.nextLine();

        if (userclass.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++) 
            {
            System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [0][i] + " " + "]"); 
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the class of your choice: ");
            userletter = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Thank you! Your seat is now reserved. Please take your ticket number.");
        }
        else if (userclass.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= classes.length; x++) 
            {
            System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [1][x] + " " + "]"); 
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the class of your choice: ");
            userletter = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Thank you! Your seat is now reserved. Please take your ticket number.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice! Try again: ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userclass.length(); i++)
        { 
        classes[i][i] = classes[i][i].replaceAll((userletter), "X");
        }


        } while (true);

    }

}
```

I would like to have a code like a working airport ticket terminal, for example is that the User wants a First class B seat then the output will be like

```
/-----------------------------/
First Class: [ A ][ B ][ C ] 
-------------------------------
Economy Class: [ D ][ E ][ F ] 
/-----------------------------/

What class would you like? F/E: F
[ A ][ B ][ C ]

Please choose one of the class of your choice: 
B
Thank you! Your seat is now reserved. Please take your ticket number.
/-----------------------------/
First Class: [ A ][ X ][ C ] 
-------------------------------
Economy Class: [ D ][ E ][ F ] 
/-----------------------------/

What class would you like? F/E:
```

"X" means occupied, but my code seems not right because in my output it is not crossing out or replacing, instead the only thing that was crossing out was the [A] and after it, it can't cross out anything of what the user will input . What is the solution? I hope this is a clear explanation

Goal: To simulate a working airport ticket terminal that the user choose what Class and what seat letter

problem: it can't cross out multiple user input. it can't be any letter rather than [A]

Answer (score 0):

Code added to replace with X

```
for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
{
    if(classes [0][i].equals(userletter))
    {
        classes[0][i] = "X";
        break;
    }
}
```

**and**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
{
    if(classes [1][i].equals(userletter))
    {
        classes[1][i] = "X";
        break;
    }
}
```

Code Removed

```
for (int i = 0; i < userclass.length(); i++)
{
    classes[i][i] = classes[i][i].replaceAll((userletter), "X");
}
```

Complete Program.

```
package machineproblem;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] classes ={{"A","B","C"},{"D","E","F"}};

        String userclass, userletter = null;

        do {



            System.out.println("/-----------------------------/");
            System.out.print("First Class: ");

            for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [0][i] + " " + "]");

            }

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Economy Class: ");

            for (int x = 0; x <= classes.length; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [1][x] + " " + "]");
            }

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("/-----------------------------/");

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print("What class would you like? F/E: ");
            userclass = input.nextLine();

            if (userclass.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [0][i] + " " + "]");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Please choose one of the class of your choice: ");
                userletter = input.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
                {
                    if(classes [0][i].equals(userletter))
                    {
                        classes[0][i] = "X";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Thank you! Your seat is now reserved. Please take your ticket number.");
            }
            else if (userclass.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= classes.length; x++)
                {
                    System.out.print("[" + " " + classes [1][x] + " " + "]");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Please choose one of the class of your choice: ");
                userletter = input.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++)
                {
                    if(classes [1][i].equals(userletter))
                    {
                        classes[1][i] = "X";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thank you! Your seat is now reserved. Please take your ticket number.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice! Try again: ");
            }


        } while (true);

    }

}
```

Comment: you are still missing one use case though, Once a ticket is reserved/booked, it shouldn't be booked again.